# Why does $\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) \pm \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ equal $2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

The specific calculation is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B$$

$$\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)=?$$

This is one of the [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

Comment: $2*cos(A)cos(B)$, but the $\pm sinAsinB$ ist still there.

Comment: Ok, I think they are just using the previous example to illustrate, that they are using identities...